# What do these AM, FFA, SEA, etc. buttons on GGTracker do?

Tags: starcraft-2, ggtracker

On [GGTracker](http://ggtracker.com/matches) there are a bunch of filter buttons. 1v1, 2v2, 3v3, and 4v4 are obvious. I think "AM" means the Americas server, "EU" means the European server. But I'm not sure what the other ones are.

[image: GGTracker screenshot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I made GGTracker. FFA stands for "Free For All" (who knew you could play a Starcraft free-for-all game?!).

And yes, AM is Americas, SEA is Southeast Asia.

Comment: You made something really nice :)

Answer (score 3):

Free for all, south East Asia, China, Korea & Taiwan